# Eloquent relation query with some column

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'm running the query which give me the result.Query is given below

Model file

```
public function units()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\PowerConsumption','device_id','device_id');
    }
```

Controller file

```
return Device::with('units')->where('user_id',2)->get();
```

Result of this query is:

```
[{
device_id: 1,
user_id: 2,
device_name: "Bulb 1",
relay_num: 22,
sensor_num: 4,
status: 1,
created_at: "2016-07-11 02:11:32",
updated_at: "2016-07-19 08:25:30",
units: [
{
p_id: 1,
device_id: 1,
unit: 0.022121944444444,
month: "7",
hour: "1",
minute: "0",
created_at: "2016-07-18 00:00:00",
updated_at: "2016-07-18 00:00:00"
},
{
p_id: 2,
device_id: 1,
unit: 0.022121944444444,
month: "7",
hour: "1",
minute: "5",
created_at: "2016-07-18 00:00:00",
updated_at: "2016-07-18 00:00:00"
}
]
```

But I want to run this Query

```
Device::with('units')->groupBY('hour')
                ->selectRaw('round(sum(unit),4) as yAxis,hour as xAxis')
                ->where('user_id',2)->get();
        }
```

And this query generate error like

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 713:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'unit' in 'field list' (SQL: select round(sum(unit),4) as yAxis,hour as xAxis from `devices` where `user_id` = 2 group by `hour`)
```

So please help me in query.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$devices = Device::with(['units' => function($query){
        $query->selectRaw('device_id,round(sum(unit),4) as yAxis,hour as xAxis');
    }])
    ->where('user_id',2)
    ->get()
    ->each(function ($item, $key) {
        return $item->units->groupBy('xAxis');
    });
```

Comment: Result of this query  [
{
device_id: 1,
user_id: 2,
device_name: "Bulb 1",
relay_num: 22,
sensor_num: 4,
status: 1,
created_at: "2016-07-11 02:11:32",
updated_at: "2016-07-19 08:25:30",
units: [ ]
}
]

Comment: please try my updated answer, I have added device_id into column list which is FK of the table

Answer (score 0):

```
$devices = Device::with(['units' => function($query){
        $query->selectRaw('device_id,round(sum(unit),4) as yAxis,hour as xAxis')->groupBy('xAxis);
    }])
    ->where('user_id',2)
    ->get();
```